# URL prefixes inserted by controllers during rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some simple controllers and views in a chain with static html pages at the end of the chain thus:

**ControllerA -> ControllerB -> index.html**

Controller A redirects to an action in Controller B, which then renders the html.
Controller C is a 3rd controller that should be accessible only by a link from a href in the html.

If the browser directly visits the html page at 'myDomain.com/index.html' then its Bootstrap-based HTML5 page is rendered and all links within it work perfectly.

However, using the Rails chain causes the html page to be rendered perfectly but many of the links do not work because the URLs in the GET are wrong in the following manner:

**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/controllerB/home/ControllerC/desiredAction")**

So, the problem is that all links in the html page are getting prepended with the last activated action path of the controller that rendered the html. Naturally, no such route exists.

I believe, from previous experiments, that the same issue arises with redirects instead of renders.

What affects the formation of the **URL** from a **static html page** link that has been rendered from a controller?

The routes.rb does attempt to route the action (perhaps I misunderstand the documentation):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
    root :controller => 'static', :action => '/public/index.html'

    # Example of regular route:
    #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
    get 'controllera/actiona'
    get 'controllera/actionb'

    get 'controllerb/home/:id', to: 'controller_b#home'
    get 'controllerc/desiredAction', to: 'controller_c#desiredAction'
end
```

and the triggering html in the static page:

```
    <a href="controllerc/desiredAction" title="My title">
```

Comment: as you are using rails controller you need to specify route for that action in your `routes.rb` file even though you are rendering a static page

Comment: Thank you for the edits anusha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the reference link in the html should be specifying an *absolute* rather than relative path:

```
    # note: the path now begins with a '/', making it absolute
    <a href="/controllerc/desiredAction" title="My title">
```

Previously, without the '/' prefix, the path was taken as being *relative* to the current controller action that was performing the render. With the '/' prefix, the first component of the path is now the desired target controller.

This works for rendering the html with a controller or directly accessing the html page by a browser.

Answer (score 1):

In your static html page just define link with controller, action and id and set the value of id to `nil`

For example

```
<%= link_to "Some Page", :controller => "your_destination_controller", :action => "your_action", :id => nil %>
```

then everything will be fine. comment your problem if you still getting error.

Comment: This appears to be a recommendation for a dynamic html (.erb) page, not a static html (.html) page that does not understand controllers, actions and ids.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether its either (.html) or (.erb) the action will evaluate the embedded ruby and renders the template.

Comment: This **does** work when the page is rendered from the controller B. For _most_ users this would be a good workaround, though it does mix in Rails code into an otherwise pure html file. However, the suggested fix becomes displayed text when it is accessed directly from a browser, breaking the page. We need a solution that works both ways and would still like to understand (the actual question) why all html URLS are being prepended by the rendering controller's path?